# alphanumeric or "Version sort" in awk array traversal

Tags: sorting, awk

I work with bioinformatic files that have a combination of characters and numbers in a row like below

EDIT updated Example

```
chr1    1    100
chr10   1    500
chr2    33   52
chr5    11   66
chr22   99   1052
chr11   444  2141
chr2    555  1200
chr7    300   444
chr7    44   222
chr21   24   6023
chr16   224  5521
chr3    3    200
chrX    6234    79593
chr1    5291    5500
chrY    204  310
```

which I want to sort like this

```
chr1    1    100
chr1    5291    5500
chr2    33   52
chr2    555  1200
chr3    3    200
chr5    11   66
chr7    44   222
chr7    300   444
chr10   1    500
chr11   444  2141
chr16   224  5521
chr21   24   6023
chr22   99   1052
chrX    6234    79593
chrY    204  310
```

I am using controlled array transversal to sort these as I scan them with for loops, but the established sorting methods are either numerical, string, or type sorting.  I would like something exactly like the GNU `sort -V` sorting.   In the link below I see that I can build a custom function for sorting, but I am not sure how to do this for alphanumeric values.

I had the idea to do something like this and sort the letter values and numeric parts separately and the figure out how to combine them, but I'm not sure exactly how to do that.

```
echo "d23FgE55" | awk '{alph=$1;num=$1;gsub("[0-9]+","-",alph);gsub("[A-z]+","-",num);print alph,num}'
d-FgE- -23-55
```

**EDIT**

I apologize, one of the answers reminded me of some of the more complicated examples I run into sometimes that made me ask about something closer to `sort -V` behavior.

**Unsorted example**

```
chr1_KI270708v1_random  9240458 9393655
chrUn_KI270589v1        5789405 6182867
chr19_GL383576v1_alt    4363702 4753141
chr8_KI270820v1_alt     1008865 1426444
chrUn_GL000220v1        7612088 7825236
chrUn_KI270591v1        9457975 9812609
chr19_GL949747v2_alt    1578276 2033118
chr13_KI270841v1_alt    8680841 9033557
chr17_KI270859v1_alt    3996864 4344945
chr20_GL383577v2_alt    3002112 3480396
chrUn_KI270322v1        1563181 1629375
chrUn_KI270419v1        5482364 5893900
chrUn_KI270310v1        4229845 4626802
chr17_KI270907v1_alt    1735306 2201566
chr9    2052238 2476827
chr1_KI270713v1_random  7260088 7358876
chr19_KI270891v1_alt    7485890 7719006
chr19_KI270917v1_alt    7816269 7864474
chrUn_KI270378v1        8848225 9158581
chr19_KI270933v1_alt    1600444 2095219
chr3_KI270937v1_alt     9902343 10113942
chr12_KI270904v1_alt    6924313 7067502
chrUn_GL000214v1        2468418 2728693
chr19_KI270884v1_alt    2760167 3027068
chrUn_KI270582v1        6390491 6398266
chr5_KI270897v1_alt     324409  548890
chr1_GL383520v2_alt     3718510 3948906
chr19_KI270888v1_alt    3809944 3824324
chr11_JH159137v1_alt    6090599 6480896
chr1_KI270762v1_alt     4196600 4684821
chr11_KI270831v1_alt    2112401 2490081
chr5_GL339449v2_alt     7220557 7718111
chr19_KI270889v1_alt    8709969 8823256
chr19_KI270931v1_alt    6356216 6811953
chr5_GL383530v1_alt     109389  128439
chr11_KI270927v1_alt    2119470 2348459
chr17_KI270730v1_random 404268  854145
chrUn_KI270387v1        7430161 7648856
chr10   2656835 2873499
chr19_GL383573v1_alt    7863497 7896279
chrUn_KI270741v1        1292450 1371680
chrUn_KI270335v1        7360266 7748998
chr9_GL383539v1_alt     3394859 3499461
chrX    4490524 4892623
chrUn_KI270311v1        963681  1069745
chr11_JH159136v1_alt    8171978 8319851
chr17_JH159148v1_alt    3708868 3984631
chrUn_KI270544v1        7025954 7392905
chr19_KI270888v1_alt    9683785 10166473
chrUn_KI270521v1        6924036 7001552
chr1_KI270710v1_random  8843336 9304602
chr19_GL949746v1_alt    8572018 8832793
chrUn_KI270322v1        9392841 9512920
chrUn_KI270366v1        3332191 3576201
chr13_KI270841v1_alt    9033828 9276044
chr19_GL949748v2_alt    3321575 3743545
chr16   3704062 4122526
chr17_GL383563v3_alt    7476487 7845527
chr8_KI270810v1_alt     8499569 8873953
chr22_KI270732v1_random 9187626 9418154
chr20_GL383577v2_alt    3031797 3421627
chr9_GL383541v1_alt     3771485 3927905
chr9_KI270720v1_random  8948742 9157627
chr16_KI270854v1_alt    7278604 7297845
chr1_KI270763v1_alt     1518275 1527443
chrUn_KI270517v1        3377374 3454859
chr15_KI270850v1_alt    6358541 6822565
chr22_KB663609v1_alt    4944645 4971886
chr7_KI270806v1_alt     9032201 9471652
chrUn_KI270438v1        8523562 8944980
chr17_KI270730v1_random 3544067 3796807
chr18   1856815 2144546
chr20_KI270869v1_alt    2269342 2353172
chr5_GL383530v1_alt     2139701 2285854
chr8_KI270819v1_alt     7048265 7503415
chr17_JH159148v1_alt    7040113 7042904
chr5_KI270793v1_alt     9363008 9816819
chr19_KI270931v1_alt    1794178 2143519
chr3_KI270778v1_alt     2228100 2549359
chr19_KI270932v1_alt    8320855 8486835
chr12_GL877876v1_alt    3736839 3820171
chr12_GL877876v1_alt    2805577 2974710
chr4_KI270789v1_alt     3309756 3669565
chr19_KI270917v1_alt    9443280 9678387
chr11_KI270831v1_alt    8603751 9028904
chrUn_KI270387v1        5189812 5439563
chrUn_KI270507v1        599827  666674
chr1_KI270711v1_random  6111532 6446935
chr2_KI270773v1_alt     8604675 8922311
chr16_KI270856v1_alt    5855373 6089898
chr3    3097856 3436204
chr13_KI270840v1_alt    3127654 3295739
chr15_KI270849v1_alt    8948327 9336376
chr18_KI270863v1_alt    3984764 4166006
chr19_KI270920v1_alt    5554949 5919294
chr12   6624798 7106478
chr4_GL383528v1_alt     2099770 2280753
chr2_KI270769v1_alt     8706329 9147304
chr8_KI270812v1_alt     6146462 6388606
```

**Sorted Output**

```
chr1_GL383520v2_alt     3718510 3948906
chr1_KI270708v1_random  9240458 9393655
chr1_KI270710v1_random  8843336 9304602
chr1_KI270711v1_random  6111532 6446935
chr1_KI270713v1_random  7260088 7358876
chr1_KI270762v1_alt     4196600 4684821
chr1_KI270763v1_alt     1518275 1527443
chr2_KI270769v1_alt     8706329 9147304
chr2_KI270773v1_alt     8604675 8922311
chr3    3097856 3436204
chr3_KI270778v1_alt     2228100 2549359
chr3_KI270937v1_alt     9902343 10113942
chr4_GL383528v1_alt     2099770 2280753
chr4_KI270789v1_alt     3309756 3669565
chr5_GL339449v2_alt     7220557 7718111
chr5_GL383530v1_alt     109389  128439
chr5_GL383530v1_alt     2139701 2285854
chr5_KI270793v1_alt     9363008 9816819
chr5_KI270897v1_alt     324409  548890
chr7_KI270806v1_alt     9032201 9471652
chr8_KI270810v1_alt     8499569 8873953
chr8_KI270812v1_alt     6146462 6388606
chr8_KI270819v1_alt     7048265 7503415
chr8_KI270820v1_alt     1008865 1426444
chr9    2052238 2476827
chr9_GL383539v1_alt     3394859 3499461
chr9_GL383541v1_alt     3771485 3927905
chr9_KI270720v1_random  8948742 9157627
chr10   2656835 2873499
chr11_JH159136v1_alt    8171978 8319851
chr11_JH159137v1_alt    6090599 6480896
chr11_KI270831v1_alt    2112401 2490081
chr11_KI270831v1_alt    8603751 9028904
chr11_KI270927v1_alt    2119470 2348459
chr12   6624798 7106478
chr12_GL877876v1_alt    2805577 2974710
chr12_GL877876v1_alt    3736839 3820171
chr12_KI270904v1_alt    6924313 7067502
chr13_KI270840v1_alt    3127654 3295739
chr13_KI270841v1_alt    8680841 9033557
chr13_KI270841v1_alt    9033828 9276044
chr15_KI270849v1_alt    8948327 9336376
chr15_KI270850v1_alt    6358541 6822565
chr16   3704062 4122526
chr16_KI270854v1_alt    7278604 7297845
chr16_KI270856v1_alt    5855373 6089898
chr17_GL383563v3_alt    7476487 7845527
chr17_JH159148v1_alt    3708868 3984631
chr17_JH159148v1_alt    7040113 7042904
chr17_KI270730v1_random 404268  854145
chr17_KI270730v1_random 3544067 3796807
chr17_KI270859v1_alt    3996864 4344945
chr17_KI270907v1_alt    1735306 2201566
chr18   1856815 2144546
chr18_KI270863v1_alt    3984764 4166006
chr19_GL383573v1_alt    7863497 7896279
chr19_GL383576v1_alt    4363702 4753141
chr19_GL949746v1_alt    8572018 8832793
chr19_GL949747v2_alt    1578276 2033118
chr19_GL949748v2_alt    3321575 3743545
chr19_KI270884v1_alt    2760167 3027068
chr19_KI270888v1_alt    3809944 3824324
chr19_KI270888v1_alt    9683785 10166473
chr19_KI270889v1_alt    8709969 8823256
chr19_KI270891v1_alt    7485890 7719006
chr19_KI270917v1_alt    7816269 7864474
chr19_KI270917v1_alt    9443280 9678387
chr19_KI270920v1_alt    5554949 5919294
chr19_KI270931v1_alt    1794178 2143519
chr19_KI270931v1_alt    6356216 6811953
chr19_KI270932v1_alt    8320855 8486835
chr19_KI270933v1_alt    1600444 2095219
chr20_GL383577v2_alt    3002112 3480396
chr20_GL383577v2_alt    3031797 3421627
chr20_KI270869v1_alt    2269342 2353172
chr22_KB663609v1_alt    4944645 4971886
chr22_KI270732v1_random 9187626 9418154
chrUn_GL000214v1        2468418 2728693
chrUn_GL000220v1        7612088 7825236
chrUn_KI270310v1        4229845 4626802
chrUn_KI270311v1        963681  1069745
chrUn_KI270322v1        1563181 1629375
chrUn_KI270322v1        9392841 9512920
chrUn_KI270335v1        7360266 7748998
chrUn_KI270366v1        3332191 3576201
chrUn_KI270378v1        8848225 9158581
chrUn_KI270387v1        5189812 5439563
chrUn_KI270387v1        7430161 7648856
chrUn_KI270419v1        5482364 5893900
chrUn_KI270438v1        8523562 8944980
chrUn_KI270507v1        599827  666674
chrUn_KI270517v1        3377374 3454859
chrUn_KI270521v1        6924036 7001552
chrUn_KI270544v1        7025954 7392905
chrUn_KI270582v1        6390491 6398266
chrUn_KI270589v1        5789405 6182867
chrUn_KI270591v1        9457975 9812609
chrUn_KI270741v1        1292450 1371680
chrX    4490524 4892623
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html

Comment: `sort -V your_input`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be all you need if you don't mind letters sorting before numbers in a numeric sort (or can find a locale to use where that isn't the case):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ vals[gensub(/chr/,"",1,$1)][$2][$3] }
END {
    OFS = "\t"

    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
    for (chr in vals) {
        for (beg in vals[chr]) {
            for (end in vals[chr][beg]) {
                print "chr"chr, beg, end
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
chrX    6234    79593
chrY    204     310
chr1    1       100
chr1    5291    5500
chr2    33      52
chr2    555     1200
chr3    3       200
chr5    11      66
chr7    44      222
chr7    300     444
chr10   1       500
chr11   444     2141
chr16   224     5521
chr21   24      6023
chr22   99      1052
```

The above uses GNU awk for arrays of arrays and sorted_in.

Comment: This works great even on my much more complicated example above.  I think this is lucky because the alphanumerics that happen after the first "chrN" are a constant space.  I guess if I'm wanting to put the strings at the end I can use @anubhava s example above.

Comment: My answer won't work for the more complicated example in your question as it'll ignore every string after the first number in the first field since that's what awk does when converting a string to a number, strip trailing non-numeric chars, and I'm using numeric comparisons. So when it sees `chr19_KI270891v1_alt` and `chr19_KI270917v1_alt` it'll just ignore everything from the `_` on and the output order for those 2 strings will be undefined. Please put your question back as it was and ask a new question with your new requirements and example.

Answer (score 2):

A `gnu-awk` approach that splits input into numerical and string arrays and then use 2 different sorting types:

```sh
awk '{
   v = gensub(/^[^0-9]+/, "", "1", $1)
   if (v ~ /[0-9]/)
      narr[v,$2] = $0
   else
      sarr[v,$2] = $0
}
END {
   PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"
   for (i in narr) print narr[i]
   PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
   for (i in sarr) print sarr[i]
}' file
```

**Output:**

```sh
chr1_GL383520v2_alt     3718510 3948906
chr1_KI270708v1_random  9240458 9393655
chr1_KI270710v1_random  8843336 9304602
chr1_KI270711v1_random  6111532 6446935
chr1_KI270713v1_random  7260088 7358876
chr1_KI270762v1_alt     4196600 4684821
chr1_KI270763v1_alt     1518275 1527443
chr2_KI270769v1_alt     8706329 9147304
chr2_KI270773v1_alt     8604675 8922311
chr3    3097856 3436204
chr3_KI270778v1_alt     2228100 2549359
chr3_KI270937v1_alt     9902343 10113942
chr4_GL383528v1_alt     2099770 2280753
chr4_KI270789v1_alt     3309756 3669565
chr5_GL339449v2_alt     7220557 7718111
chr5_GL383530v1_alt     109389  128439
chr5_GL383530v1_alt     2139701 2285854
chr5_KI270793v1_alt     9363008 9816819
chr5_KI270897v1_alt     324409  548890
chr7_KI270806v1_alt     9032201 9471652
chr8_KI270810v1_alt     8499569 8873953
chr8_KI270812v1_alt     6146462 6388606
chr8_KI270819v1_alt     7048265 7503415
chr8_KI270820v1_alt     1008865 1426444
chr9    2052238 2476827
chr9_GL383539v1_alt     3394859 3499461
chr9_GL383541v1_alt     3771485 3927905
chr9_KI270720v1_random  8948742 9157627
chr10   2656835 2873499
chr11_JH159136v1_alt    8171978 8319851
chr11_JH159137v1_alt    6090599 6480896
chr11_KI270831v1_alt    2112401 2490081
chr11_KI270831v1_alt    8603751 9028904
chr11_KI270927v1_alt    2119470 2348459
chr12   6624798 7106478
chr12_GL877876v1_alt    2805577 2974710
chr12_GL877876v1_alt    3736839 3820171
chr12_KI270904v1_alt    6924313 7067502
chr13_KI270840v1_alt    3127654 3295739
chr13_KI270841v1_alt    8680841 9033557
chr13_KI270841v1_alt    9033828 9276044
chr15_KI270849v1_alt    8948327 9336376
chr15_KI270850v1_alt    6358541 6822565
chr16   3704062 4122526
chr16_KI270854v1_alt    7278604 7297845
chr16_KI270856v1_alt    5855373 6089898
chr17_GL383563v3_alt    7476487 7845527
chr17_JH159148v1_alt    3708868 3984631
chr17_JH159148v1_alt    7040113 7042904
chr17_KI270730v1_random 3544067 3796807
chr17_KI270730v1_random 404268  854145
chr17_KI270859v1_alt    3996864 4344945
chr17_KI270907v1_alt    1735306 2201566
chr18   1856815 2144546
chr18_KI270863v1_alt    3984764 4166006
chr19_GL383573v1_alt    7863497 7896279
chr19_GL383576v1_alt    4363702 4753141
chr19_GL949746v1_alt    8572018 8832793
chr19_GL949747v2_alt    1578276 2033118
chr19_GL949748v2_alt    3321575 3743545
chr19_KI270884v1_alt    2760167 3027068
chr19_KI270888v1_alt    3809944 3824324
chr19_KI270888v1_alt    9683785 10166473
chr19_KI270889v1_alt    8709969 8823256
chr19_KI270891v1_alt    7485890 7719006
chr19_KI270917v1_alt    7816269 7864474
chr19_KI270917v1_alt    9443280 9678387
chr19_KI270920v1_alt    5554949 5919294
chr19_KI270931v1_alt    1794178 2143519
chr19_KI270931v1_alt    6356216 6811953
chr19_KI270932v1_alt    8320855 8486835
chr19_KI270933v1_alt    1600444 2095219
chr20_GL383577v2_alt    3002112 3480396
chr20_GL383577v2_alt    3031797 3421627
chr20_KI270869v1_alt    2269342 2353172
chr22_KB663609v1_alt    4944645 4971886
chr22_KI270732v1_random 9187626 9418154
chrUn_GL000214v1        2468418 2728693
chrUn_GL000220v1        7612088 7825236
chrUn_KI270310v1        4229845 4626802
chrUn_KI270311v1        963681  1069745
chrUn_KI270322v1        1563181 1629375
chrUn_KI270322v1        9392841 9512920
chrUn_KI270335v1        7360266 7748998
chrUn_KI270366v1        3332191 3576201
chrUn_KI270378v1        8848225 9158581
chrUn_KI270387v1        5189812 5439563
chrUn_KI270387v1        7430161 7648856
chrUn_KI270419v1        5482364 5893900
chrUn_KI270438v1        8523562 8944980
chrUn_KI270507v1        599827  666674
chrUn_KI270517v1        3377374 3454859
chrUn_KI270521v1        6924036 7001552
chrUn_KI270544v1        7025954 7392905
chrUn_KI270582v1        6390491 6398266
chrUn_KI270589v1        5789405 6182867
chrUn_KI270591v1        9457975 9812609
chrUn_KI270741v1        1292450 1371680
chrX    4490524 4892623
```

Comment: This mostly works, but it doesn't take into account the other two columns.  See my uupdated example set

Comment: I apologize, I feel like I keep moving the goal-posts on you.  I like your example, but sometimes I get things that are very complicated mixtures of alpha-numeric values, which this doesn't work with.

Comment: I have updated my answer. It doesn't depend on first column starting with certain characters like `chr`. There might be some edge cases but it will work for all the cases you've provided in question.

Comment: It was a bad copy/paste. I pasted generated output again and `chr11_*` looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- first field will always start with at least one letter and be followed by 0 or more numbers (ie, `[:alpha:]+[:digit:]*`)
- letters and digits will never be intermixed (eg, `d23FgE55` won't occur)
- first field is made up only of letters and numbers (ie, `[:alnum:]`)
- entire input file fits into ~60% of available memory (otherwise loading entire file into an `awk` array may risk an 'out of memory' error)

Adding a few more data points to the input:

```
$ cat dat.raw
chr1    1    100
chr10   1    500
chr2    33   52
bec9   3   17
chr5    11   66
chr22   99   1052
chr11   444  2141
chr2    555  1200
chr7    300   444
defA   3    15
def7   13    15
def7   3    15
chr7    44   222
chr21   24   6023
chr16   224  5521
chr3    3    200
chrX    6234    79593
chr1    5291    5500
chrY    204  310
```

Using `GNU awk` for array of arrays and `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`:

```
awk '
     { keyL=gensub(/([[:digit:]])/,"","g",$1)    # strip numbers from 1st field
       keyN=gensub(/([[:alpha:]])/,"","g",$1)    # strip letters from 1st field

       if ( keyN == "" ) keyN=999999999          # if no numbers in 1st field use a really big number to insure these rows go to the end of the list

       arr[keyL][keyN][$2]=$0                    # arr[] index = 1st field letters / 1st field numbers / 2nd field
     }

END  { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"      # sort 1st index as string
       for (i in arr) {
           PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"  # sort 2nd/3rd indices as numbers
           for (j in arr[i])
               for (k in arr[i][j])
                   print arr[i][j][k]
       }
     }
' dat.raw
```

This generates:

```
bec9   3   17
chr1    1    100
chr1    5291    5500
chr2    33   52
chr2    555  1200
chr3    3    200
chr5    11   66
chr7    44   222
chr7    300   444
chr10   1    500
chr11   444  2141
chr16   224  5521
chr21   24   6023
chr22   99   1052
chrX    6234    79593
chrY    204  310
def7   3    15
def7   13    15
defA   3    15
```

Comment: Hum... I added a new example that is probably the most complicated I will ever run into.  This behaves very strangely with that example.

Comment: yeah, kinda figured you'd come back with a *'but what about ...'* update :-)  while implementing a full blown `version / sort -V` sort method in `awk` would be an interesting exercise ... 'fraid I don't have anything (else) at this point other than repeating dawg's comment ... `use sort -V`

Answer (score 0):

The version sorting [rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Version_002dsort-ordering-rules.html#Version_002dsort-ordering-rules) of GNU utilities are not trivial to fully implement.

Given your second example as `unsorted` and `desired`:

```
head -n 5 unsorted
chr1_KI270708v1_random  9240458 9393655
chrUn_KI270589v1        5789405 6182867
chr19_GL383576v1_alt    4363702 4753141
chr8_KI270820v1_alt     1008865 1426444
chrUn_GL000220v1        7612088 7825236
...

head -n 5 desired
chr1_GL383520v2_alt     3718510 3948906
chr1_KI270708v1_random  9240458 9393655
chr1_KI270710v1_random  8843336 9304602
chr1_KI270711v1_random  6111532 6446935
chr1_KI270713v1_random  7260088 7358876
...
```

Here is a ruby. It works on fully on your second example:

```
ruby -e 'ar=$<.read.split(/\r?\n/); 
puts ar.sort_by {|e| e.split(/(\d+)/).map {|a| a =~ /\d+/ ? a.to_i : a }}.
    join("\n")' unsorted >t_ruby
```

Now compare `t_ruby` to `desired`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{idx[$0]=FNR; next}
{print $0, FNR, idx[$0]}
' t_ruby desired | head -n 10
chr1_GL383520v2_alt     3718510 3948906 1 1
chr1_KI270708v1_random  9240458 9393655 2 2
chr1_KI270710v1_random  8843336 9304602 3 3
chr1_KI270711v1_random  6111532 6446935 4 4
chr1_KI270713v1_random  7260088 7358876 5 5
chr1_KI270762v1_alt     4196600 4684821 6 6
chr1_KI270763v1_alt     1518275 1527443 7 7
chr2_KI270769v1_alt     8706329 9147304 8 8
chr2_KI270773v1_alt     8604675 8922311 9 9
chr3    3097856 3436204 10 10
... line by line the same ...
```

Answer (score 0):

When I posted this question, this is what I was looking for.  I am sure this algorithm could be sped up and shortened a lot.  It splits the string into numeric sections and string sections and compares section by section.  I believe it behaves the same as gnu `sort -v` with the exception of how it deals with `.`

I like the other answers because they run quickly, but I think this function should work for arbitrarily long and weird alpha-numeric groups.

```
awk '
function ivsort(i1,v1,i2,v2){
    s=sprintf("%c",0)
    split(gensub("[0-9]+",s"&"s,"g",i1),f1,s)
    split(gensub("[0-9]+",s"&"s,"g",i2),f2,s)
    for (val=1;val<=length(f1);val++){
        if (!(val in f2)){
            return -1
        }
        if (f1[val]==f2[val]){
            continue
        }
        if (f1[val]+0 != f1[val] && f2[val]+0 != f2[val]){
            return (f1[val]>f2[val])?1:-1
        }
        else{
            return (f1[val]+0)-(f2[val]+0)
        }
    }
    if (length(f2) > length(f1))
        return -1
    else
        return length(i1) - length(i2)
}
```

to Run add that function to the top of your awk program and set it as the value for `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`

```
PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "vsort"
    for (x in a){
        print x
    }
```

Comment: This is incomplete implementation of [-V rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Version_002dsort-ordering-rules.html#Version_002dsort-ordering-rules). You would need to 1) reorder `~` to sort before any other character; 2) reorder ASCII codes 91-96 to sort before all digits and letter; 3) Adding a leading zero does not fully get you a natural sort order -- consider `"0900"` and `"01000"` which still sort lexicographically incorrectly...

Comment: Consider also the two strings `foo7a.7z` and `foo07.7z` These are sorted backwards by this algorithm vs sort -V.

Comment: @dawg I see I was dumb and said I wanted something exactly like sort -V.  I do need to work on my clarity.  I guess I said that because I wasn't actually aware of the ~ and non-alphabetic character sorting conditions.  I  just wanted an algorithm that sorted numbers numerically and letters alphabetically, even when they were mixed.    Also, are you saying that `"01000"` should sort before `"0900"`?  Just curious.  Are you saying numbers that have a leading zero should be sorted alphabetically?

Comment: If you are just looking for numbers to be considered in sorting as numbers, rather than the ASCII characters of those numbers, this is called [Natural Sort Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order). That is significantly easier to implement in gawk than the rules associated with fully implementing `sort -V`

Comment: @dawg Thank you for explaining that.  I can't believe I've never run across the term "Natural Sort" in the last decade.  This is one reason I like asking questions on stack overflow is the people who are willing to share solutions and give a lot more context.  It's a good place to learn what you didn't know you didn't know :).